# Discord.py autorole issue

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm new at programming.I want to create an autorole system in my Discord server.I tried this:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):
   async def on_member_join(member):
   server = client.get_guild(serverid)
   role = server.get_role(roleid)
   await member.add_roles(role)
```

But it's not working.Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why isn't it working? As well, please include a [mcve] and any errors that you may be getting as a code block. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This works for me so I guess this will be useful for you:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} Started!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
    role_id = 1234567890123456
    role = get(member.guild.roles, id=role_id)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    

client.run('your bot token here')
```

`role_id` is Integer.

must have member intents turned on, if you don't know how to enable read this:
[**Here**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).